# How to Override Java dependency in .m2 folder

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 java projects. Project A is depending on Project B.

Always I will make the code changes to Project B and uploading artifacts to Artifactory with same version(like 1.0.0). **I don't want to change the version**.

Project A is able to download the Project B dependency from Artifactory for the first time and placed in .m2 folder.

**Issue:** I made any changes to Project B and uploaded to Artifactory with the same version number(like 1.0.0). Now Project A is not downloading the latest artifacts from Artifactory. it is using which is already downloaded and placed in .m2 folder.

So how Project A always download the dependency from Artifactory instead of using .m2 folder.

Comment: Either you change the version, artifactId or groupId, or you use a different repo and later commits, or you have he same code. This seems like asking: "I want my OS to be called Windows XP, but I want the functionality to be that of Windows 10"

Comment: HI @Stultuske, always we cant work as per the standards. there may be some cases to work like this kind of situations also. So please let me know if you have answers for my questions.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. If you have a fixed version, this is not possible. That's why during development, the version numbers get the suffix -SNAPSHOT (basically: temporary version). each version with a version nr without this suffix, is considered a release, and won't be overwritten in your local repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-snapshot version is expected to be the same regardless where you found it.  This behavior is expected and allows caching artifacts locally.

You should switch to snapshot versioning (where you do not have to update the version number when building) and only use releases for final code that will never change.

Comment: still not clear on how this would solve the issue. if you build project B with an updated snapshot, it would indeed give another dependency, but as soon as you re-build project A with this snapshot, you would still get the same.

Comment: If a snapshot is found in a newer version on a repository it will be downloaded and replace the local copy.

Comment: That's indeed my point; the OP wants to have the identical same version for both projects, but he wants the (very same) dependency to result in different content/behavior for one project, but remain the same as before for the other.

Comment: @Stultuske That is not how I read the question.  He is building project B elsewhere and is not having his changes picked up by project A.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use *-SNAPSHOTS* for your project B  and then use *mvn -U clean* for your project A. This should always download the latest snapshot. When you are done with your changes in project B release it.